# Is it possible to define an unordered_map with a vector<T> as value?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl, unordered-map

I have a pattern of vectors with their getters like this:

```
vector<A>& getA() const { return a; }
vector<B>& getB() const { return b; }
vector<C>& getC() const { return c; }
...
```

I'm interesed in having some kind of function like `vector<T>& getByName(string s) const` so that i can call the function this way: `getByName("A")`,`getByName("B")` and so on.

I've tried using an unordered map, but I haven't found any proper way to make a line like this work: `unordered_map< string, vector<T> >`.

A, B, C... are completely different structs, so a polymorphic solution is not what I'm looking for as far as possible.

As `vector<T>` is a container with a fixed size (24 bytes if I'm not wrong), I don't see why the map is not able to store those bytes somewhere in memory no matter the vector's type.

Comment: If `A` `B` and `C` are all different types then there's no way this works, because the biggest issue is you cannot declare `std::vector<T>` to hold different, non-polymorphic types

Comment: You could have a template function `get_vector<T>()` that would return a `vector<T>`. `T` would however have to be specified at compile-time, so it would not work with runtime values if that was your idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As vector is a container with a fixed size (24 bytes if I'm not wrong), I don't see why the map is not able to store those bytes somewhere in memory no matter the vector's type.

Because C++ is a strongly typed language, and the fact that the types `vector<A>`, `vector<B>` and `vector<C>` are the same *size* doesn't matter, since they are different *types*.

A `pair<int16_t, int16_t>` is the same size as an `int32_t` (on most implementations), but that doesn't make them interchangeable.

You could (I suppose) have a `map<string, variant<...>` or a `map<string, any>`, but that will require you to manage all the types yourself.

[Later]

> I'm interesed in having some kind of function like `vector<T>& getByName(string s)`

The problem with such a function is that you would have to specify (at compile time) a type that the function would return. You would like to have the return type determined by the value of the parameter passed to the function at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know about variant / any and after a good read that was exactly what i needed for this issue. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `vector<A>`, `vector<B>`,.. in one `unordered_map`, because they have different types. I think the solution below closest to your need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class my_unordered_map :
        public unordered_map<string, vector<T>> {
};

template<typename T>
vector<T>& get_by_name(const string& s, my_unordered_map<T>& mm) {
    return mm[s];
}

class A {
public:
    string name;

    A() = default;

    explicit A(const string& s) : name{s} {}
};

int main() {
    vector<A> vec_a1{A{"A1"}};

    my_unordered_map<A> mm;
    mm["A"] = vec_a1;

    vector<A>& vec_a2 = get_by_name("A", mm); //vec_a2 is the same as mm["A"]
    vec_a2.emplace_back("B");

    for (const auto& item : vec_a2) {
        cout << item.name << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```